# access the stackpanel inside a datatemplate in windows phone

Tags: listbox, datatemplate, windows-phone, itemtemplate

I want to access the StackPanel UIElement inside a ItemTemplate(datatemplate) of listbox:

```
<ListBox x:Name="list">
<ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
       <StackPanel x:Name="stk" >
           // some other stuffs
       </StackPanel>
    </DataTemplate>
   </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

but how?

Comment: i have the same issue, have you possible solved this?

Comment: hi @user2042227 , i post this question since i want my list to have alternate color.. it works, but sad to say, I included a property rowColor on my model, which is a wrong approach..